# Hilbert space theory and their applications

Tags: reference-request, hilbert-spaces, book-recommendation, quantum-mechanics

What are the best books that discuss the theory of Hilbert spaces and their applications to quantum mechanics for the beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum Mechanics in Hilbert Space , by E. Prugovecki;

http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1007&context=mathsp

Hilbert Space Operators in Quantum Physics, by J. Blank, P.Exner, M. Havlícek